# Create a folder upon install

Tags: joomla-2.5

In my Joomla install there's already a template installed, and with this template came the folder "template" in media. I want to place my "menu background images" folder within this "template" folder upon installing my menu module. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create [install-uninstall-script](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_simple_module/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file) file and on installation of the module move the images folder in to the desired location.

Another way using xml syntax, but this is restricted to media directory only. In case you want to move your module media to some directory other than Joomla-root/media then this solution will not work.

```
   <media folder="media" destination="Template_directory">
            <folder>css</folder>
            <folder>js</folder>
    </media>
```

Comment: are you sure there's no easier way? I feel a script like this would be an unnecesarily big addition to such a small module. I was hoping there was a way to fix it in the xml file.

Comment: yes there is one more way by using xml file..i have added this in answer

Comment: Great, just what I was looking for, thanks!!